# How to do a frequency table where column values are variables?

Tags: r, frequency

I have a DF named JOB. In that DF i have 4 columns. Person_ID; JOB; FT (full time or part time with values of 1 for full time and 2 for part time) and YEAR. Every person can have only 1 full time job per year in this DF. This is the full time job they got most of their income during the year.

```
DF
PERSON_ID      JOB     FT     YEAR
   1         Analyst   1      2018
   1         Analyst   1      2019
   1         Analyst   1      2020
   2         Coach     1      2018
   2         Coach     1      2019
   2         Analyst   1      2020
   3         Gardener  1      2020
   4         Coach     1      2018
   4         Coach     1      2019
   4         Analyst   1      2020
   4         Coach     2      2019
   4         Gardener  2      2019
```

I want to get different frequency in the lines of the following question:
What full time job changes occurred from 2019 and 2020?

I want to look only at changes where FT=1.

I want my end table to look like this

```
 2019       2020    frequency
Analyst    Analyst      1
Coach      Analyst      2
 NA        Gardener     1
```

I want to look at the data so that i can say 2 people moved from they coaching job to analyst job. 1 analyst did not change their job and one person entered the labour market as a gardener.

I tried to fiddle around with the table function but did not even get close to what i wanted. I could not get the YEAR's to go to separate variables.

10 Bonus points if i can do it in base R :)

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty but worked:

```
# split df by year
df_2019 <- df[df$YEAR %in% c(2019) & df$FT == 1, ]
df_2020 <- df[df$YEAR %in% c(2020) & df$FT == 1, ]

# rename Job columns
df_2019$JOB_2019 <- df_2019$JOB
df_2020$JOB_2020 <- df_2020$JOB

# select needed columns 
df_2019 <- df_2019[, c("PERSON_ID", "JOB_2019")]
df_2020 <- df_2020[, c("PERSON_ID", "JOB_2020")]

# merge dfs
df2 <- merge(df_2019, df_2020, by = "PERSON_ID", all = TRUE)
df2$frequency <- 1
df2$JOB_2019 <- addNA(df2$JOB_2019)
df2$JOB_2020 <- addNA(df2$JOB_2020)

# aggregate frequency
aggregate(frequency ~ JOB_2019 + JOB_2020, data = df2, FUN = sum,  na.action=na.pass)

  JOB_2019 JOB_2020 frequency
1  Analyst  Analyst         1
2    Coach  Analyst         2
3     <NA> Gardener         1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not R base but worked:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>%
  filter(FT==1, YEAR %in% c(2019, 2020)) %>%
  group_by(YEAR, JOB, PERSON_ID) %>%
  tally() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = YEAR, values_from = JOB) %>%
  select(-PERSON_ID) %>%
  group_by(`2019`, `2020`) %>%
  summarise(n = n())


  `2019`  `2020`       n
  <chr>   <chr>    <int>
1 Analyst Analyst      1
2 Coach   Analyst      2
3 NA      Gardener     1
```